# How to get a simpler solution of this differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions, special-functions

```
$Assumptions = U > 0 && K > 0 && R > 0 && CC > 0
sol = DSolve[{U/K f''[x] + (U^2/K - 1 + 2/(x + R) U/K) f'[x] - (U + 2/(x + R) + 
              CC U) f[x] == 0}, {f}, {x}]
```

The output includes some complex functions, such as `HypergeometricU` and `LaguerreL`. So is there any way to deal with this differential function so that the solution does not contain the Laguerre function?

Comment: "does not contain the Laguerre function?" - and yet you're cool with the Tricomi function being there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what's so unacceptable about `LaguerreL` that anything would be acceptable in its place, but from [functions.wolfram.com](http://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/LaguerreL3/26/01/01/0001/),
we have the following transformation:

```
simp = HoldPattern[LaguerreL[n_, λ_, z_]] :>
  (Gamma[λ + n + 1] HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{-n}, {λ + 1}, z])/
   Gamma[n + 1];
```

We can apply it to the solution

```
Assuming[U > 0 && K > 0 && R > 0 && CC > 0,
 sol = DSolve[
   {U/K f''[x] + (U^2/K - 1 + 2/(x + R) U/K) f'[x] - (U + 2/(x + R) + CC U) f[x] == 0},
   {f}, {x}] /. simp
 ]
```

Simplified solution:

```
Assuming[U > 0 && K > 0 && R > 0 && CC > 0,
 FullSimplify[f[x] /. First@sol]
 ]
(*
  (1/(U (R + x))) * E^(-(((-K + U^2 + Sqrt[K^2 + 2 (1 + 2 CC) K U^2 + U^4]) * 
    (R + x))/(2 U))) (-Sqrt[K^2 + 2 (1 + 2 CC) K U^2 + U^4] (R + x) C[2] * 
      Hypergeometric1F1[
       (K + U^2 + Sqrt[K^2 + 2 (1 + 2 CC) K U^2 + U^4]) / 
        Sqrt[K^2 + 2 (1 + 2 CC) K U^2 + U^4],
       2,
       (Sqrt[K^2 + 2 (1 + 2 CC) K U^2 + U^4] * (R + x))/U] +
     U C[1] HypergeometricU[
       (K + U^2)/Sqrt[K^2 + 2 (1 + 2 CC) K U^2 + U^4],
       0,
       (Sqrt[K^2 + 2 (1 + 2 CC) K U^2 + U^4] (R + x))/U])
*)
```

Well, there's still no `LaguerreL` even after simplifying.